# Nom propre employé comme nom commun : première lettre en majuscule ou non ?

Tags: orthographe, noms-propres, majuscules

Un livre donne comme exemple :

> Un hercule est un homme très fort.

Tandis qu'un autre donne :

> Cet homme est un Tartuffe.

Pourquoi cette différence à savoir **hercule avec un h minuscule** et **Tartuffe avec un T majuscule** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/tartufe), il n'y a pas de majuscule lorsqu'on parle d'un « tartuf(f)e. »

Comment: Alors quand on utilise un nom propre comme nom commun ce dernier-ci commence par une lettre minuscule (un tartufe (hypocrite), un hercule (très fort), etc.) ?

Comment: @dimitris: Pour autant que je le sache, la réponse est oui.

Comment: C'est noté. Merci !